# Image is not display in index page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a problem with the index page. On this index page, we can see the uploaded Ad details like Ad title, description, and link except for the uploaded image. When I inspect i can see

```
<img src="/images/Ad/ad2.png" width="50px" height="50px">
```

On the index page, i use this code

```
<td>
    <img src="@Url.Content(String.Format("/images/Ad/{0}",item.ImagePath))" width="50px" height="50px" />
</td>
```

This is my Controller

```
public IActionResult Create([Bind("AdID,Title,ImagePath,Description,Link")] AdTbl adTbl, List<IFormFile> FormFile)
        {
            if (FormFile != null && FormFile.Count > 0)
            {
                string folderName = "images/Ad"; 
                string webRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
                string newPath = Path.Combine(webRootPath, folderName);
                if (!Directory.Exists(newPath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);
                }
                foreach (IFormFile item in FormFile)
                {
                    if (item.Length > 0)
                    {
                        string fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(item.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');
                        string fullPath = Path.Combine(newPath, fileName);
                        adTbl.AdID = Guid.NewGuid();
                        adTbl.ImagePath = fileName;
                        using (var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
                        {
                            item.CopyTo(stream);
                        }
                        _adTblRepository.CreateAd(adTbl);
                    }
                }
                _notyf.Success("Advertisement added successfully");
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));

            }
            return View(adTbl);
        }
```

**The main thing is that the same code is using on different pages and that's worked. And I noticed that one thing when we change the location this problem occurs again

Comment: Did you use `base="~"` to define the base root in your `_Layout.cshtml` file? 

Comment: You'd better offer your image file structure(in wwwroot?), the index view and it's related action, I tested your code but it works as charm.